# Find all matching results in column and output their adjacent rows

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, office365, vlookup

#### Summary

I have a database of ~1500 entries. Some of them have more than one entry (up to 5) under the same identifier. I have a pre-set list of IDs I would like to check to see if they have multiple records, and if so, pull all of them, so I can compare them for differences.

#### Current solution

I currently have this working correctly, using a method to pull the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th response respectively. The current formula is:
`=INDEX('DATABASE'!$B:$B,SMALL(IF($A2='DATABASE'!$A:$A,ROW('DATABASE'!$A:$A)-ROW('DATABASE'!$A$1)+1),1))` for the 1st result, `=INDEX('DATABASE'!$B:$B,SMALL(IF($A2='DATABASE'!$A:$A,ROW('DATABASE'!$A:$A)-ROW('DATABASE'!$A$1)+1),2))` for the second, and so on. In this case, the above code would check the value in A2 (ID2Check), and then do a match for it on the 'DATABASE' sheet in column A. If it matches, it will return the first value that matches from column B. The second piece of code above does the same, except it returns the second match from column B. ID2Check is populated by me, and the Results 1-5 are the code output. For example:

**Database:**

| ID | Data Item |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | Lemons |
| 111 | Greenhouse |
| FOO | Computer |
| AAA | Monitor |
| CAT | Coffee |
| ORANGE | Pintglass |
| 123 | Birthday |
| FOO | Avengers |
| AAA | Plasters |
| FOO | NachoTaco |

**Code output:**

| ID2Check | Result 1 | Result 2 | Result 3 | Result 4 | Result 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Lemons | Monitor |  |  |  |
| 123 | Birthday |  |  |  |  |
| FOO | Computer | Avengers | NachoTaco |  |  |

#### Problem

This solution works correctly, and will pull the expected values as required. The problem is, as this code needs to be entered 5 times per identifier, and there are ~1500 records to check, I need to flash fill 7500 formulas. Unsurprisingly, this leads to Excel crashing and becoming unresponsive for the best part of 30 minutes. I am looking to find a solution that would be more efficient and stable when running en-mass. Any assistance would be appreciated.

#### Final Notes / Info

I'm using MSO 365, version 2202 (I cannot update beyond this). This will be run in the Desktop version of Excel. I would prefer this is done exclusively using formulas, but I am open to using Visual Basic if it would be otherwise impossible or incredibly inefficient.

Comment: Use `Unique` to get ID2Check column and `Transpose(Filter(...))` to get the Result columns

Comment: @chrisneilsen - ID2Check is manually populated by me. I'm looking to improve the method that populates Result 1, Result 2, Result 3, Result 4 and Result 5 from "Code Result". I thought this was clarified, but upon re-reading, I went back and made some small edits to clarify.

Comment: well, did you try the functions I mentioned?

Comment: @chrisneilsen - Sorry, didn't have time to at that particular moment, but thought I'd clarify the comment to clear up while I wasn't at my PC before being able to test. After testing, it does work. I appreciate the assistance. As someone has answered to the same effect below, I'll mark theirs as the solution. Thanks for the support nonetheless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=UNIQUE(C5:C15)
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($D$5:$D$15;$C$5:$C$15=F5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does provide the solution required, although there's a slight typo in your formula. You've used a semi-colon between $D$15 and $C$5, instead of a comma. It should be 
```=UNIQUE(C5:C15)
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($D$5:$D$15,$C$5:$C$15=F5))``` If you make the change, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: @wisp The semicolon is not an error. In my Region Excel uses semicolon instead of comma. So if you live in US, you need a comma, here in Europe we use semicolon.

Comment: thanks for clarifying - this is news to me! Apologies, I wasn't aware. As it did provide the solution, I've accepted this as answer. Thanks for your input, and TIL!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `HSTACK()` function then could try-

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A11),TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("/",FALSE,BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:A11),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,FILTER(B2:B11,A2:A11=x))))),"|","/",,,""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, `HSTACK()` isn't available in the Excel version being used (2202). I'll certainly consider this for when I have access to the functionality though - it looks super useful!